# 70-30 Tax reverse calculation get products original amount without tax

Tags: javascript, excel, logic, reverse, mathematical-optimization

There is tax called 70%-30%. Base price of product will be part in 70% and 30%.
And tax on 70% amount will be 5% and on 30% will be 18%. Here is Image sample calculated.

[image]

Now calculation is required reverse. We have 24000.00273 and tax information.
need Base amount to be calculate.

We have tried different method but amount doesn't match.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? This calculation can be simplified to _output := input · 1.089_. Now you should know how to invert it. How is this related to JavaScript?

Comment: It was just logic to be developed in JavaScript. So I had added and this might be helpful to people needs to develop in code so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculate total by:

```
total = base + ((0.05 * 0.7 * base) + (0.18 * 0.3 * base))
```

So the reverse is:

```
base = total / (1 + ((0.05 * 0.7) + (0.18 * 0.3)))
```

In JS:

```js
function reverse(amt, split1, split2, tax1, tax2) {
  return amt / (1 + ((split1 * tax1) + (split2 * tax2)));
}

var base = reverse(24000.00273, 0.7, 0.3, 0.05, 0.18);

console.log(base);
```

In Excel (formula in A6):

```
=A1/(1+((A2*A4)+(A3*A5)))
```

[image]